# Dropdown list to display default array value Angular2

Tags: arrays, angular, drop-down-menu, default

I've been trying to get my dropdown list to display the selected values, which works but when the list first loads the first value is shows is all 3 and I want it to default to job 1. How can I do this?

Angular code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector:'job-container',
    templateUrl: './job.container.html'
})

export class JobContainer {

    public jobTypes:Array<string> = ["Job 1", "Job 2", "Job 3"];

    selectedType = this.jobTypes;

    onSelect(job = this.jobTypes): void {
        this.selectedType = job;
    }
};
```

Html code:

```
<div class="container">
    <h4 translate="Job Type"></h4>
</div>
<div class ="col-10">
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" 
            id="drowdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown"
            aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            {{selectedType}}
            </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="drowdownMenuButton">
            <a class="dropdown-item" *ngFor="let job of jobTypes"
            (click)="onSelect(look)">{{job}}</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This shows what is produced:
[drop down, default value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1sQv.png)

When I click on one of the options it does display as the selected. But I want the default value shown in picture 1 gone and replaced with Job 1.
This shows one of the options selected:
[drop down option selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgV6x.png)

Comment: set selectedType = this.jobTypes[0];

Comment: I've tried this.jobTypes[0]; However it gives me an error on the line: this.selectedType = job; The error states string[] is not assignable to type string

Comment: Why are you setting `this.selectedType = job` where `job`'s default value is `this.jobTypes`? Maybe you meant to set `job = this.jobTypes[0]` as the default value in `onSelect`

Comment: Just do selectedType: any = this.jobTypes[0]; this will work

Comment: When I do job = this.jobTypes[0], it still has the problem of not being able to perform string to string[ ]. I'm not sure why that is because job is an array and so is jobTypes.

Comment: selectedType: any = this.jobTypes[0] - that worked. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved:

```
    export class JobContainer {

        public jobTypes:Array<string> = ["Job 1", "Job 2", "Job 3"];

        selectedType: any = this.jobTypes[0];

        onSelect(job = this.jobTypes): void{
            this.selectedType = job;
        }
   }
```